# Symfony2 app deployment on FTP server

Tags: ftp

I need to deploy symfony2 app on ftp server. I know I have to copy all project files here (or maybe there are more solutions)? Question is, how can I create doctrine database scheme? sorry for dummy question, I am new in this area.